# Unstable external display with M1 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, apple-silicon

The late 2020 M1 MacBook Pro does not seem to be playing well with the LG UltraWide 38WK95C 38-inch external display directly connected with a USB-C cable. The display blacks out (as if the cable physically disconnects) every hour or so. The issue usually resolves itself within a few seconds but sometimes I have to restart the computer to get it in a good state. The problem occurs with both USD-C ports and does not exist with the late 2016 MacBook Pro.

How can I diagnose and fix this external display issue?

Comment: Which cable are you using? My 4K belkin ones are working very well so far.

Comment: Same cable for both MacBooks?  The other option is to try a different monitor   Get and  use DisplayPort input and boot HDMI to match the LG as close as possible. If the issue persists, you might have a problem with the Mac itself warranting further diagnosis

Comment: @Allan: Yes, same cable for both MacBooks.

Comment: @bmike: It's the cable that came with the LG external display.

Comment: I would swap it out with a new one - you need a spare eventually and I’ve seen vendor cables be less reliable than the Belkin ones. We probably replace one in 20 of the LG over the first year and less than 1 in 100 of the Belkin.

Comment: @bmike: I followed your recommendation and bought this Belkin cable (https://www.amazon.co.uk/Belkin-F2CU049bt2M-BLK-USB-C-Monitor-Cable-Black/dp/B073KCPS2M?th=1). Will try it for a few days but unfortunately it looks like the problem persists. Did I get the right cable?

Comment: Yes - that looks like the ideal cable. Mine is white, but yours has all the things I check for on the product page.

Comment: @bmike: Thanks for confirming the cable choice. Unfortunately the new cable didn't help. The screen still blacks out several times a day. Surely there must be some sort of diagnostics to shed some insight into *why* the screen blacks out. My guess is that the GPU driver is acting funny.

Comment: Certainly @Randomblue most good analyzers start at $4,500 US (sorry they’re not cheaper) https://teledynelecroy.com/protocolanalyzer/usb/advisor-t3 someone with deep pockets and an engineer needs to pick apart if it’s the display or the Mac and then dive into the code if it’s not a faulty part. Some things can be fixed with a patch for sure, but until a trace is caught, you’ve done the easy steps.

Comment: Assuming it is a Mac OS software issue (e.g. a GPU driver crash), surely the OS would write out an error log somewhere saying that the GPU driver crashed, no?

Comment: I'd try a USB-C to HDMI adapter or cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have gone away after updating macOS Big Sur from 11.0.1 to 11.1.